# Can I use ElephantSql service as a target in bluemix data connect?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

I created a service to ElephantSql in bluemix (plan: Tiny Turtle).

I created a connection to the ElephantSql service in Data Connect. It appears in my list of Connections in Data Connect. However - It does not appear as an option when I try to use "copy to target" / "set target". Is this a restriction in Data Connect?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say that you created an ElephantSql connection, I assume you selected the PostgreSQL connection type. Data Connect supports PostgreSQL only as a source, not a target: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/dataworks_overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The table in your link explains everything. :) No PostgreSql unless its Compose PostgreSql for a target.